# Drawbacks of Eloquent relationships with "::class"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

According to a recent Laravel documentation, Eloquent model relationships are done the following way:

```php
$this->hasMany('App\Comment');
```

For instance: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many.

Why is the documentation using strings instead of `::class`? An IDE would usually ignore strings during a refactor or code completion, while using `::class` fix both issues.

```php
$this->hasMany(App\Comment::class);
```

My current guesses are:

- No update in the documentation since PHP 5.5 (which added support for `MyClass::class`).
- Eagerly loading model classes through PHP import, but loading a class is not that big.

Is there any serious drawback in using `::class` for Eloquent relationships?

Comment: Found a Laracasts article about `::class`: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-what-is-class, in the end, I see no negative point in using `::class`.

Comment: No negative and I also prefer ::class. By the way, the class is not loaded just by referring to its name with ::class. It gets loaded only when it is actually used, by instantiating, or accessing static members.

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala thank you for the additional input. This seems indeed to nullify the only negative impact I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just comes down to user preference. There are no serious differences between the two so go ahead and use whichever method you prefer. Just make sure that you are consistent throughout your application, that is the main thing.

Comment: It does indeed, since the only drawback I could think of, eager loading of the class, is not even true. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `::class` simply returns the fully qualified class name, so it's just a more neat way of writing code.